# Using an if statement with an agentset in NetLogo

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, netlogo

New to NetLogo. I am using the Fire Simple example, I added new tress with the pcolor=blue. I am trying to make a condition that the blue patch will only turn red if its 4 surrounding neighbors are red as well.

ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [
     set pcolor red 
    if (neighbors4 with [pcolor = red] > 3)
    ]

I get an error 
"> expected this input to be an agent or number or string, but got an agentset instead"

Answer (score 3):

So there are a couple small problems with your code as written.

Firstly, in NetLogo, the `if` command must be followed by a command block, [per the dictionary entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#if).  So you cannot do `command if someCheck` you have to do `if someCheck [ command ]`

Second, `neighbors4 with [color = red]` is going to give you an agent set, a collection of patches in this case.  So you cannot compare an agent set with a number, like in `neighbors4 with [pcolor = red] > 3`.  You need to get the [`count`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#count) of the agent set: `count neighbors4 with [pcolor = red] > 3`

```
ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [ 
  if (count neighbors4 with [pcolor = red] > 3) [ 
    set pcolor red 
  ] 
]
```

Also, if we notice that the inner if statement is just an extra filter on which blue patches will turn red, we can actually use the `with` statement from the outer `ask` and simplify things a bit:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = blue and (count neighbors4 with [pcolor = red] > 3)] [
  set pcolor red 
]
```

Hope that helps.